# Binary Search Tree Monad Implementation

Tags: tree, scala, monads

I've written a Binary Search Tree Monad in Scala. I would like to hear your thoughts on how to improve it (e.g. making insertion/deletion/search faster and more scalable). Also, is there a better way to implement this kind of data structure the Scala way?

[The whole code](https://github.com/melvic-ybanez/scala-bst/blob/master/ScalaBST/src/BST.scala)

Here is the trait:

```
trait BST[+A] {
  def +[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](elem: B): BST[B]
  def ++[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](bst: BST[B]): BST[B]
  def -[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](elem: B): (Option[B], BST[B])

  def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean
  def contains[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](e: B): Boolean
  def filter[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](p: A => Boolean): BST[B] = filterAcc[B](EmptyBST)(p)
  def filterAcc[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](acc: BST[B])(p: A => Boolean): BST[B]

  def flatMap[B <% Ordered[B]](f: A => BST[B]): BST[B]
  def map[B <% Ordered[B]](f: A => B): BST[B]

  def inOrder[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B
  def preOrder[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B
  def postOrder[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B
  def levelOrder[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B

  def withLeft[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](newLeft: BST[B]): BST[B]
  def withRight[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](newRight: BST[B]): BST[B]
  def orElse[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](tree: BST[B]): BST[B]
  def minChild[B >: A <% Ordered[B]]: BST[B] = minChildAcc[B](this)
  def minChildAcc[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](acc: BST[B]): BST[B]

  def toList = preOrder(List[A]())(_ :: _).reverse
}
```

And here is the implementation:

```
case object EmptyBST extends BST[Nothing] {
  def +[B <% Ordered[B]](elem: B) = BST(elem)
  def ++[B <% Ordered[B]](bst: BST[B]) = bst 
  def -[B <% Ordered[B]](elem: B) = (None, EmptyBST)

  def flatMap[B <% Ordered[B]](f: Nothing => BST[B]): BST[B] = EmptyBST    
  def map[B <% Ordered[B]](f: Nothing => B): BST[B] = EmptyBST 

  def exists(p: Nothing => Boolean) = false
  def contains[B <% Ordered[B]](e: B) = false
  def filterAcc[B <% Ordered[B]](acc: BST[B])(p: Nothing => Boolean) = acc

  def inOrder[B](z: B)(f: (Nothing, B) => B) = z
  def preOrder[B](z: B)(f: (Nothing, B) => B) = z
  def postOrder[B](z: B)(f: (Nothing, B) => B) = z
  def levelOrder[B](z: B)(f: (Nothing, B) => B) = z

  def withLeft[B <% Ordered[B]](newLeft: BST[B]) = newLeft
  def withRight[B <% Ordered[B]](newRight: BST[B]) = newRight
  def orElse[B <% Ordered[B]](tree: BST[B]) = tree
  def minChildAcc[B <% Ordered[B]](acc: BST[B]) = acc

  override def toString = "[]"
}

case class NonEmptyBST[A <% Ordered[A]](elem: A, left: BST[A], right: BST[A]) extends BST[A] {
  def +[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](newElem: B) = 
    if (newElem < elem) withLeft(left + newElem)
    else if (newElem > elem) withRight(right + newElem)
    else this

  def ++[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](bst: BST[B]) = bst.preOrder[BST[B]](this)((e, acc) => acc + e)

  def -[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](e: B) = 
    if (e < elem) (left - e) match { 
      case (opt, l) => (opt, withLeft(l)) 
    } else if (e > elem) (right - e) match { 
      case (opt, r) => (opt, withRight(r)) 
    } else (Some(elem), (left, right) match {
      case (EmptyBST, EmptyBST) => EmptyBST
      case (l, EmptyBST) => l
      case (EmptyBST, r) => r
      case (l, r) => right.minChild match {
        case EmptyBST => r.withLeft(l)
        case NonEmptyBST(min, _, _) => NonEmptyBST(min, l, (r - min)._2) 
      }
    })

  def exists(p: A => Boolean) = p(elem) || left.exists(p) || right.exists(p)
  def contains[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](e: B) = exists(_ == e)
  def filterAcc[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](acc: BST[B])(p: A => Boolean) = 
    right.filterAcc(left.filterAcc(if (p(elem)) acc + elem else acc)(p))(p)

  def flatMap[B <% Ordered[B]](f: A => BST[B]) = preOrder(f(elem))((e, acc) => acc ++ f(e))
  def map[B <% Ordered[B]](f: A => B) = preOrder[BST[B]](BST(f(elem)))((e, acc) => acc + f(e))

  def inOrder[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B) = right.inOrder(f(elem, left.inOrder(z)(f)))(f)
  def preOrder[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B) = right.preOrder(left.preOrder(f(elem, z))(f))(f)    
  def postOrder[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B) = f(elem, right.postOrder(left.postOrder(z)(f))(f))

  def levelOrder[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B) = {
    def recurse(acc: B, queue: Queue[BST[A]]): B = queue match {
      case Queue() => acc
      case h +: t => h match {
        case EmptyBST => recurse(acc, t)
        case NonEmptyBST(e, l, r) => recurse(f(e, acc), t.enqueue(l).enqueue(r))
      }
    }  

    recurse(z, Queue(this))
  }

  def withLeft[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](newLeft: BST[B]) = NonEmptyBST(elem, newLeft, right)
  def withRight[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](newRight: BST[B]) = NonEmptyBST(elem, left, newRight)
  def minChildAcc[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](acc: BST[B]) = left.minChildAcc(this)
  def orElse[B >: A <% Ordered[B]](tree: BST[B]) = this

  override def toString = elem + "[l=" + left + ", r=" + right + "]"
}

object BST {
  def apply[A <% Ordered[A]](): BST[A] = EmptyBST

  def apply[A <% Ordered[A]](elem: A, elems: A*): BST[A] = { 
    def recurse(elems: List[A],bst: BST[A]): BST[A] = 
      if (elems.isEmpty) bst
      else recurse(elems.tail, bst + elems.head)

    recurse(elems.toList, NonEmptyBST(elem, EmptyBST, EmptyBST))
  }
}
```

Comment: I remember seeing some academic paper about an efficient algorithm to implement an immutable binary tree.  I know it was referenced in some way by Martin Odersky.  Sorry, but it's really all that I remember.

Comment: It does not sound right that you are using possibly different `Ordered` implementations on each operation. (Also, nowadays -I understand this is quite old question- `Ordering` and context bounds are  preferred.)

Answer (score 1):

I have not treated Scala, but Haskell. I like some competitive programming and I thought about Tree Problems deeply. I'm sorry for the Japanese site, a tree problem and my solution are:

[Deque - Aizu Online Judge](https://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=ITP2_1_B&lang=en)

[My solution in Haskell](https://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/review.jsp?rid=3185779#1)

In Scala, the vector type `scala.collection.immutable.Vector` is similar to my above tree structure. Maybe, you can get faster implementation than the simple BST.

Each depth `d` needs `2^(d-1)` nodes, I think the following relationship:

```
1st depth = 1
2nd depth = [2, 3]
3rd depth = [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

In general,

```
left = (parent << 1);
right = (parent << 1) + 1;
parent = child >> 1;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, SE didn't notify me of your response. Thank you for the change your post should now meet the requirements to not be deleted.